# running data parser on multiple files in folder? Python

Tags: python, regex

long time lurker, but never posted here. Sorry if this isn't a good post...I made a program that uses regex to pull the names and emails out of resumes. I can get it to open a specific file in my resume folder, but getting the program to iterate over all of the files in the folder has me stumped. Here's the pseudo-code for what I'm doing:

- open resume folder

  - read file1.txt

    - execute nameFinder
    - execute emailFinder

      - create new dictionary candidateData
      - Export to Excel
  - read file2.txt
  - ...

Here's the code:

```
import re
import os
import pprint

with open('John Doe -Resume.txt', 'r') as f:

    #This pulls the first line of the resume,
    #Which is generally the name.
    first_line_name = f.readline().strip()

    #This pulls the Email from the resume.
    bulkemails = f.read()
    r = re.compile(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)')
    candidateEmail = r.findall(bulkemails)
    emails = ""
    for x in candidateEmail:
            emails += str(x)+"\n"

            #This creates the dictionary data
            candidateData = {'candidateEmail' : str(candidateEmail), \
                              'candidateName' : str(first_line_name)}

    pprint.pprint(candidateData)
```

Then, I get this as an output:

```
{'candidateEmail': "['JohnDoe@gmail.com']",
'candidateName': 'John Doe'}
```

All ready to be exported into Excel.

SO HERE"S MY QUESTION FOR YOU! How do I get it to do this for ALL of the .txt files in my resume folder, and not just the file I specify? Also, any cod critique would be greatly appreciated, Thanks guys! :D

Comment: I have one more question, that isn't directly related to my last question, but I don't want to clutter up the main board with not high-level questions...
When my parser runs through the resumes, sometimes there are two values (emails) that I would want it to add to my dictionary under the same key. Basically, IF >2 strings returned, append the second (and third and fourth etc.) value to the same key

Comment: Basically, have ALL of the emails (The data strings that are being pulled) where if more than one is found, added to the key candidateEmail in the candidateData dictionary . seems I would use the .append method, just can't get the " if more than two strings" argument working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use glob to iterate over all .txt files in your directory and then run the function on each file. Add this to the start

```
import re
import os
import glob
import pprint

os.chdir("resumes")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        #Rest of your execution code here
```

EDIT: In answer to your question in the comments:

```
import re
import os
import glob
import pprint

candidateDataList = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:

        #This pulls the first line of the resume,
        #Which is generally the name.
        first_line_name = f.readline().strip()

        #This pulls the Email from the resume.
        bulkemails = f.read()
        r = re.compile(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)')
        candidateDataList.append({'name':str(first_line_name),
                                  'email':r.findall(bulkemails)})

pprint.pprint(candidateDataList)
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: I was trying to get listdir to put a string inside the open() function...it just...wasn't one of my brighter moments hahaha

Comment: No problem :-)! If you want to use listdir instead you could just do `for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):`

and then use `if file.endswith(".txt"):` to get just .txt files.

If this solved your answer I'd love an up-vote and if you click the tick under the vote buttons on my response to accept my answer that would be awesome!

Comment: I have one more question, that isn't directly related to my last question, but I don't want to clutter up the main board with not high-level questions...

Comment: When my parser runs through the resumes, sometimes there are two values (emails) that I would want it to add to my dictionary under the same key. Basically, IF >2 strings returned, append the second (and third and fourth etc.) value to the same key

Comment: Basically, have ALL of the emails, if more than one is found, added to the key candidateEmail in the candidateData dictionary . seems I would use the .append method, just can't get the " if more than two strings" argument working...

Comment: My only thing with that, is that eventually, I would also want phoneNumbers, location, etc too. Currently, the way I see it working is this: Load the CV > Pull name, add to dic > pull email, add to dic> (eventually) pull phone number, add to dic > pull location, add to dic...

Eventually, I'd have something looking like this,

candidateData =
 {'candidateName': 'John Doe',
 'candidatePhoneNumber': str(8888888888),
  'candidateEmail': 'jd@gmail.com',        
  'location': 'Phoenix'}

Quite a bit of data. So, I like my creating one dic per iteration, then saving that dic to Excel, and restarting

Comment: Would you have another suggestion as to how to go about doing it? I have quite a lot of CV's hahaha

Comment: You seem to be suggesting making lots of separate dictionaries, and then loading them into Excel all at once I think.

Comment: I see, then yes I'd make a list of dictionaries (make them inline rather than creating a new one and populating it). I've edited the code in my original post again to something that does this. The output here is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary contains the parsed data from each CV. You can then easily add more things (phone number etc.) as you parse them. To use it, just iterate over the list and then call whatever key:value pair you want for each dictionary (CV).

Comment: and then just add all of those dictionaries in the list to the excel spreadsheet at once at the very end of the program?

Comment: Sure, if you're looking for the Excel output then have a completely separate Excel Parse Out function which gets called at the end of the program and takes as it's argument the full list of dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like my way was VERY resource intensive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100031/discussion-between-gage-brklacich-and-jakob).

Answer (score 1):

@Jakob's answer is spot on. I only wanted to mention a nice alternative which I usually prefer myself, the `pathlib`:

```
import re
import pprint
from pathlib import Path

resumes_dir = Path("resumes")
for path in resumes_dir.glob("*.txt"):
    with path.open() as f:
        #Rest of your execution code here
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this? Is there an advantage to doing it this way?

Comment: It might not matter too much here, but I have found using `Path` to result in much cleaner and more elegant code. To provide an example, concatenating path elements is just `Path("dir") / "file"`. It provides a more object-oriented approach to path handling vs the imperative approach in `os` functionality.